# Alternative to permutation test in spatstat for large dataset

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

New to spatial statistics and I've been using it to analyse super-resolution microscopy datasets. I've gotten some very interesting summary statistics (especially K functions) that show differences between two groups of data.  I'd like to perform hypothesis testing on the two groups to be able to answer the question - do the two sets of point patterns come from the same point process?

I have a hyperframe containing the point patterns (ppp) in one column, and a factor to denote grouping in the second column. Each group has 10 point processes. Each point process has at least 1500000 points to analyse.

```
>superResData
Hyperframe:
       locs Experiment
X1    (ppp)      basal
X2    (ppp)      basal
X3    (ppp)      basal
X4    (ppp)      basal
X5    (ppp)      basal
X6    (ppp)      basal
X7    (ppp)      basal
X8    (ppp)      basal
X9    (ppp)      basal
X10   (ppp)      basal
X1.1  (ppp)    insulin
X2.1  (ppp)    insulin
X3.1  (ppp)    insulin
X4.1  (ppp)    insulin
X5.1  (ppp)    insulin
X6.1  (ppp)    insulin
X7.1  (ppp)    insulin
X8.1  (ppp)    insulin
X9.1  (ppp)    insulin
X10.1 (ppp)    insulin
```

As discussed in the Baddeley et al. book on spatial statistics, I used:

```
studpermu.test(superResData, locs ~ Experiment, summaryfunction=Kinhom)
```

but unfortunately, I'm running into a memory problem caused by the size of our datasets:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.2 Gb
```

Even running this analysis on Google Colab Pro fails because of a lack of memory.

Are there alternative tests or functions that can be used to accommodate this huge dataset?
Thanks for the advice in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about the function `studpermu.test` in the `spatstat` family of packages (the function is now in the sub-package `spatstat.core`).

Please provide more information about the context in which you used `studpermu.test`. What arguments were passed to `studpermu.test`? Was the point pattern data organised in a hyperframe, or as a list of lists of point patterns? Were any other messages or warnings printed before or after the error message? Which summary function did you choose?

Please rerun the same command, wait for the error, and type `traceback()`, and show us the output. This will tell us exactly at what point the error occurred, which is vitally important.

`studpermu.test` is user-contributed code written in R (rather than C). It is probably not very efficient for large datasets. We will put this on the list of things to improve.

Try the following tricks:

- add the argument `correction="none"` in the call to `studpermu.test`. This will suppress the calculation of edge correction factors, which can sometimes be computationally expensive. You don't need edge corrections in your data because there are so many points.
- compute the K function of one or two of your point patterns, and visually judge what would be a reasonable range of distance values (in the sense that the interesting information is contained in this range of distances). Then add the argument `rinterval=c(0, rmax)` to the call to `studpermu.test`, where `rmax` is the reasonable maximum value of distance. (The default range of distance values may be too large.)

Comment: I've edited the original post to add more info about the dataset and the arguments to the `studpermu.test` function. I'm rerunning the command now and will post the results of `traceback()` soon. In another PC, I'm rerunning `studpermu.test()` with the two modifications that you've suggested, and will also update on the outcome of that. Thank you!